# Bootstraps source code for bfh-number class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Today I've found simple and efficient solution for allowing only numbers in `input[type=text]`, it's bootstrap's `bfh-number` class.

I've used it like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control bfh-number">
```

I didn't know before that this is possible to do with css only. That's why I've tried to find source code for that class. I've [downloaded bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v3.3.7.zip) source and searching in `css/bootstrap.css`and several other `css` files, but couldn't find this class. Where is it located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bfh-number` located in separate stylesheet not in `bootstrap` stylesheet. You need to download a plugin called `bootstrap-formhelpers`

http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/assets/css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css

Please download the plugin form the below link.

https://github.com/winmarkltd/BootstrapFormHelpers/tree/master/js

Comment: Thanks. It seems that this is not done purely with css how I've thought it's done initially, but it's a combination of css and javascript, although only css class is put on the element.